# Visual Studio - SharePoint 2010 - Include Assembly > Quick Question

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I have a quick question....building a VS 2010 SharePoint project and I am referencing a custom assembly.  I can reference this assembly in my code and it works fine to write code and all.  When I deploy the project to SharePoint my Feature Activation code will not run because the custom assembly does not get deployed with the project.

I have set Copy Local to TRUE on the referenced assembly.  Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you Create SharePoint Project in Visual Studio 2010, you will see a Item called Package in it.Click open it and bottom left corner click on Advanced, you will see an option to add additional assemblies , add as many you want > all assemblies you select here will get deployed as a Part of SHarePoint Package you create.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can use [ilmerge.exe](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com%2Fdownloads%2Fdetails.aspx%3Ffamilyid%3D22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&ei=zT9QTKffAcuXnAevrqn8BQ&usg=AFQjCNEC-_P_sXQvEiCp8lnyM9vX47HzzA&sig2=qNxx9eTsJIrYtUmYXMarKw) to bundle satellite managed assemblies into your executable, making it portable and more easily deployed. I use it all the time, it works great.

You can set up a build event in VS2010 to do this automatically whenever you build, too, though it can be a bit slow (I have it set as a Release-only build event for this reason).

Comment: not really...thanks for the reponse though.  I want to ship my custom assembly to the GAC when I deploy my SharePoint project.